# 2 states roundable numeric text box with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, textbox

I want to have an html numeric text box with 2 states, when focused, it has to show all decimal places, and when focus is lost, only show 2 decimals. I've almost achieved it.

**HTML:**

```
<input data-bind="attr: { 'data-numericvalue': valueToRound}" class="numerictextbox"
       type="number"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var viewModel = {
    valueToRound: ko.observable(7.4267),
};

//NUMERIC TEXTBOX BEHAVIOUR
$('.numerictextbox').focusout(function () {
  $(this).attr("data-numericvalue", this.value); //this line does not update the viewModel
  this.value = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-numericvalue")).toFixed(2);
});
$('.numerictextbox').focusin(function () {
  if ($(this).attr("data-numericvalue") !== undefined) this.value = $(this).attr("data-numericvalue");
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7zzt3Lbf/64/

But my problem is that when focusout occurs, it doesn't update bound property, viewModel in this case. This is a simplified version of my code, so I want it to be generic for a lot of properties in my real scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing in too much jQuery :)

Knockout has `event` bindings and a `hasFocus` binding to deal with UI input.

In the example below I've made a viewmodel that has a hidden `realValue` observable which stores the unmodified input. The `displayValue` limits this number to a 2 digit number when `showDigits` is false.

I've used `hasFocus` to track whether we want to show the whole number: it's linked to `showDigits`.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.showDigits = ko.observable(true);
  
  var realValue = ko.observable(6.32324261);

  this.displayValue = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return this.showDigits() 
        ? realValue()
        : parseFloat(realValue()).toFixed(2);
    },
    write: realValue
  }, this);
};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="value: displayValue, hasFocus: showDigits" type="number"/>
```

**Edit: After comment that a computed is too much extra code: here's how to wrap the computed logic in a reusable extender:**

```js
ko.extenders.digitInput = function(target, option) {
  var realValue = target,
      showRealValue = ko.observable(false),
      displayValue = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
          return showRealValue() 
            ? realValue()
            : parseFloat(realValue()).toFixed(2);
        },
        write: realValue
      }, this);
  
  displayValue.showRealValue = showRealValue;
  
  return displayValue;
};


var ViewModel = function() {
  this.value1 = ko.observable(6.452345).extend({ digitInput: true });
  this.value2 = ko.observable(4.145).extend({ digitInput: true });
};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: value1, hasFocus: value1.showRealValue" type="number"/>
<input data-bind="value: value2, hasFocus: value2.showRealValue" type="number"/>
```

Comment: This works ok, but I think it doesn't fit my needs because I have a lot of properties in my viewmodel, lets call them valueToRound1, valueToRound2, valueToRound543...etc. Then I cannot have, realvalueToRound1, showDigitsOfRealValueToRound1, displyValueToRound1, etc...Is there any way to store this "sub-properties" for every binding?

Comment: I've added an example that shows how you can put the computed layer in an extender. This makes it easy to create one of those digit input values without having to rewrite the focus and computing logic for every case.