# 2 states roundable numeric text box in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textbox

The behaviour I want to achieve is a numeric textbox that shows 2 decimal places when not focused, and every decimal position when focused. It is the same behaviour that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41676486/5147720):

```js
ko.extenders.digitInput = function(target, option) {
  var realValue = target,
      showRealValue = ko.observable(false),
      displayValue = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
          return showRealValue() 
            ? realValue()
            : parseFloat(realValue()).toFixed(2);
        },
        write: realValue
      }, this);
  
  displayValue.showRealValue = showRealValue;
  
  return displayValue;
};


var ViewModel = function() {
  this.value1 = ko.observable(6.452345).extend({ digitInput: true });
  this.value2 = ko.observable(4.145).extend({ digitInput: true });
};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: value1, hasFocus: value1.showRealValue" type="number"/>
<input data-bind="value: value2, hasFocus: value2.showRealValue" type="number"/>
```

But now I want to use `AngularJS` instead of `Knockoutjs`. I am really new to this framework so I dont know if the correct way of do this is using a service, a factory or just calling a generic event on the main controller with `ng-blur` and `ng-focus`. I am also using Typescript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working solution **In Typescript:**

```
interface INumericTextBox extends angular.IDirective {
}

interface INumericTextBoxScope extends angular.IScope {
}

interface INumericTextBoxAttributes extends angular.IAttributes {
    ngModel: string
}

interface IElement extends angular.IAugmentedJQuery {
    value: string
}

NumericTextBox.$inject = ["$window"];
function NumericTextBox($window: angular.IWindowService): INumericTextBox {
    // Usage:
    //     <numeric-textbox></numeric-textbox>
    // Creates:
    // 

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: link
    }

    function link(scope: INumericTextBoxScope, element, attrs: INumericTextBoxAttributes, ngModelController) {
        var realValue;
        element.bind('focus', function (scope) {

            if (realValue != null) this.value = realValue;
        })

        element.bind('blur', function (scope) {

            realValue = this.value;
            this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
        })

        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (data: number) {
            //convert data from model format to view format
            if (data != null) {
                realValue = data;
                data = parseFloat(data.toFixed(2));
            }
            return data; //converted
        });
    }
}

angular.module("app").directive("numericTextbox", NumericTextBox);
```

Working javascript example here: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wVDXCziA9d9Emg59cyYk?p=preview)